# Are interface members abstract?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

Well I know members in an interface act like they were abstract, but are they abstract actually? I mean that I do not need to use that keyword so I am not sure whether its implicit or they are not abstract technically...Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not abstract - they are a contract defined by the interface.  "abstract" has a specific meaning which only applies to classes.

That being said, they act very similarly to an abstract member in a class - any type implementing the interface must either implement the member or be abstract itself.

Answer (score 2):

They are abstract in concept, as a class that implements the interface must either implement every member or declare itself to be `abstract`.

They are not `abstract` in a technical sense, as only classes are `abstract`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Abstract methods implicitly are virtual.

Interface implementations do not need to be virtual. (*In fact, it is possible to explicitely implement 'conflicting' interfaces (i.e. interfaces declaring identical member signatures). This would not be possible with the `vtable single dispatch`[1], because a single vtable slot cannot be filled twice*)

[1] classical implementation method for virtual inheritance

Comment: +1. Good call, that's a significant distinction. Indeed, you could also implement conflicting *implementations*, where a more derived class re-implements an interface implemented in a parent class. Hilarity ensues.

Comment: Too true. However, with explicit interface implementation the client usually doesn't know, because he get's only the IInterestingInterface he expects. IMHO explicit interfaces have become a tad bit obsolete: I have felt the need to use them in my classes only to make up for the lack of _closures_ (fixed in 3.5) or the Java-style non-static inner (_nested_) classes.... Oh the hilarity we've been missing out on will be greatly compensated for by the confusion between Enumerables, Queryables, Observables which all differ subtly and will create new hilarious semantic surprises. Future proof!

Answer (score 0):

They are implicitly abstract in the sense that they have no behavior defined, only the signature of the member is described.

I don't know offhand what it looks like at the IL (and probably will never need to know, actually).